# Linux Wi-Fi network compatible laser printer

Tags: linux, wifi, printer, floss

I am looking for a black/white laser printer.

Requirements:

- No requirement for proprietary / non-free drivers
- No requirement for proprietary printer plugin
- Linux compatible using Wi-Fi / LAN

Bonus:

- Black/white sufficient (color is needlessly more expensive)
- Android compatible
- Wi-Fi
- USB
- Scanning